# Why is my question not yet opened?

Tags: support, closed-questions

My question, [Which movie started the common practice of 2 sets of closing credits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60454/which-movie-started-this-2-sets-of-closing-credits) is still closed.

I've added so many details to it and I am ready to add even more of them.

Is there any reason it is still not reopened?

Comment: I've nominated it for reopening. Seems a legit question to me (even though it may be hard to answer it). Now it depends on the reviewers, whether they will vote to reopen it or not.

Comment: For the details of the reopening process see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) meta post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @chanandler linked to, questions get reopened by community consensus. Same as closures. Normally its 5 users, or a mod. In this case it was 3 users and a mod (counting as 2 instead of 5). At this moment, 3 people (myself included) have voted to reopen. Others may agree and vote to reopen as well. But it may not happen. There is no guarantee. Them's the breaks.

That said, I've edited it some to help improve the chances it gets reopened. Even without the edits, the question is plainly on-topic, and I knew what you were asking right away when I saw it.

Comment: Reopened now....